# Integrating POI in android Studio to read PPTx

Tags: android, apache-poi

I am integrating POI to read PPTx and i am using following jar and i have tried most of the jar. So please tell me the right way to integrate POI in android studio to read PPTx. I do not know the reason why i am getting this error.

```
implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar')
implementation files('libs/poi-3.9.jar')
implementation files('libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/dom4j-1.6.1.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-collections4-4.1.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
implementation files('libs/poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar')
```

and getting this error.

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow.<init>(XMLSlideShow.java:82)
        at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow.<init>(XMLSlideShow.java:87)
        at com.pptviewer.pptfilereader.MainActivity.openppt(MainActivity.java:137)
        at com.pptviewer.pptfilereader.MainActivity.access$600(MainActivity.java:43)
        at com.pptviewer.pptfilereader.MainActivity$ConvertPPTXTOPNG.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:128)
        at com.pptviewer.pptfilereader.MainActivity$ConvertPPTXTOPNG.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:116)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
05-14 18:28:32.444 15297-15297/com.pptviewer.pptfilereader W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6349)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
    Caused by: org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSLFFactory.java:66)
        at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:403)
        at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:155)
        at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow.<init>(XMLSlideShow.java:80)
        ... 14 more
05-14 18:28:32.445 15297-15297/com.pptviewer.pptfilereader W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSLFFactory.java:64)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.class$(XmlBeans.java:43)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildStreamToNodeMethod(XmlBeans.java:247)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.<clinit>(XmlBeans.java:134)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.getContextTypeLoader(XmlBeans.java:327)
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.SldMasterDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlideMaster.<init>(XSLFSlideMaster.java:68)
        ... 20 more
05-14 18:28:32.446 15297-15297/com.pptviewer.pptfilereader W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pptviewer.pptfilereader-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.pptviewer.pptfilereader-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.pptviewer.pptfilereader-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
05-14 18:28:32.447 15297-15297/com.pptviewer.pptfilereader W/System.err:    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI? What happens if you upgrade? What happens if you use one of the various Android wrappers for Apache POI?

Comment: Can You Please suggest all Jars so that i can use them